# Swift/arm64-apple-ios.swiftinterface:23320: Fatal error crash

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, crash

After the recent update to Xcode 14, this crash occurs every time I perform a network request, parsing the data, The exception occurs in the DataCompression implementation parsing the data code

At present, this problem is found by updating to Xcode 14. It is normal to use the original Xcode 13.4

DataCompression Extension Data func gunzip()

```
        let ftr: GZipFooter = withUnsafeBytes { (bptr: UnsafePointer<UInt8>) -> GZipFooter in
            // +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
            // |     CRC32     |     ISIZE     |
            // +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
            return bptr.advanced(by: count - 8).withMemoryRebound(to: UInt32.self, capacity: 2) { ptr in
                return (ptr[0].littleEndian, ptr[1].littleEndian)
            }
        }
```

The following is the relevant screenshot information of the crash
[image: crash]
[image: crash]

Answer (score 1):

I found the reason, because when DataCompression is decompressing data, there is an exception when it adapts to Swift 5.7. Currently, I am using version 3.6.0, and I can update it to 3.7.0.
https://github.com/mw99/DataCompression